# How do panpsychists explain death?

Tags: panpsychism

If mindlike features are a fundamental part of reality, what exactly happens during death? What exactly is changing at death?

From a physical perspective, we know what changes after death. We know that your heart stops beating, your skin cools down, and your brain stops functioning.

However, from a panphysicist perspective, what exactly is happening? Correct me if I’m wrong, but it is said that everything is conscious under panpsychism. So what happens at death? Does experience stay the same? Or does it become different for the various constituents of our body? If so, what divides these constituents and is this division arbitrary?

Lastly, if the nature of mind does change at death, why does this change happen to coincide with the destruction of certain vital functions under panpsychism?